# Windows Phone - XamlParseException

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

I get a XamlParseExeption while navigating to my page. The problem seems be to something with toolkit TiltEffect or TransitionService:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Unknown parser error: Scanner 2147500037. [Line: 16 Position: 38]
  Source=System.Windows
  LineNumber=16
  LinePosition=38
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at ContactChooser.ContactChooserPage.InitializeComponent()
       at ContactChooser.ContactChooserPage..ctor()
  InnerException:
```

The last line is number 16:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="ContactChooser.ContactChooserPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the snippet you've posted. Can you show a complete reproduction of the issue and confirm which version of the toolkit you are using.

Comment: I'm using version 4.2012.10.30 of the WPToolkit. I get the same error if I set a another control of the Toolkit in my code, for example the PhoneTextBox. It seems to be something wrong with Toolkit itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the issue. I have two projects in my solution: the main project who is using the TiltEffect and a sample project for testing the main project. The solution of the issue is that I need to add a reference to the Toolkit on both projects, not only on the project who is using the component.

Comment: Yes, you have to reference it in ALL the projects that use it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should not use the Tilt effect on whole page, just on the controls you want to be tilt enabled.

Comment: If you set it at the page level it will be applied to all the controls it supports that exist in the page. It's much simpler than applying the effect to individual controls if you have lots of them and want it applied to them all.